# How to delay img show in Angular 8 and rxjs 6?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have the current template:

```
<img [src]="evaluatePicPath(data)" *ngIf="data">
```

Now the problem that I need to change the data on runtime so the image
is actually change while the page is open.
I'm able to see the correct image *the updated one) on the screen but
the console throw 404 error:

```
http://localhost:8080/myapp/files/bar.png 404
```

I'm thinking that the image is not existing for 1 second? Any idea how
delay showing the img src ? I've tried [ngModelOptions]="{ debounce: 2000 }"
but this attribute is available only for input.
Thanks.

Comment: Try this `<img *ngIf="data" [src]="evaluatePicPath(data)">`. Instead of `data` in `*ngIf` use your own condition to avoid `404 Not found` error.

Comment: in template loop like some gallery of thumbnails? If that is the case what is triggering the loop render?

Comment: I'm saving data, then calling load method. I've tried to debounce the loading method as well.

Answer (score 0):

V1: You can try to use `[attr.src]` instead of `[src]`.
Check it here please: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pxddpv

**UPDATE: 1**
Also you can use this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pxddpv-txg8ni.

Comment: The setTimeout cause the image to not display, but I don't see the error.

Comment: @user2304483 if you set `[attr.smth...]` to `undefined` that means that attribute won't be added to element. I used setTimeout only for example.

Comment: I don't understand the solution

Comment: If I understand correctly you would like to render image (change the src attribute) in runtime and render after some delay?

Comment: I get error for async ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: 'http://localhost:8080/myapp...' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'

Comment: @user2304483 your link is incorrect. But I think I know what problem you have. You should import **CommonModule**: https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195633/discussion-between-mr-alex-and-user2304483).

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve the problem I've update the Java servlet to serve images after
1 second. I have used:

```
Thread.sleep(1000);
```